# How to make .bin binary from linux source code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a modified linux kernel, which I want to run on top of a hypervisor. Till now I've always been using uImage but the script in hypervisor requires an executable. How can I create binary executable from linux source code? Is the vmlinux created after building, the final binary executable?

Answer (score 1):

1. vmlinux is an ELF file not a binary.
2. kernel build may create zImage, that is a binary file. You can find
   it at `$kernel/arch/arm/boot/zImage` in case of ARM.   Keep in mind
   that zImage is a zip compressed binary file and a header is attached
   at the top of zImage. With this header, zImage can decompress by
   itself.

To run zImage, you need to move pc(program counter) to the first point of zImage.